# EnablePartialRendering="true" causing PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Script entries not loaded yet. with debug="false"

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, microsoft-ajax

When I run my website not in debug mode but after publishing then on page with update panel on every update I get :

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Script entries not loaded yet.
```

I found solution setting `EnablePartialRendering="false"` os `ToolkitScriptManager` but then UpdatePanel just doesn't work as UpdatePanel and whole page is refreshing.

Here is how I load stuff in master:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"
            ScriptMode="Auto"
            EnablePageMethods="true"
            EnablePartialRendering="true"
            LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
            AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled"
            RoleService-LoadRoles="false"
            EnableCdn="false"
            EnableScriptGlobalization="false">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I resolve the issue?

And... everything works pretty fine if I set .NET compilation debug flag to `true` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful link on the issue ongoing
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27517

Answer (score 0):

I know its old thread but for anyone facing this problem .
I have no idea why , but for me the only workaround was setting ***CombineScripts="False"*** for ***ToolkitScriptManager*** , give it a try